# Как лучше всего получить никнейм в фейсбуке по ID?

Tags: php, redirect, facebook

Есть ID пользователя в facebook. Например 100014222106738
Если прикрепить этот ID к домену, вот так https://www.facebook.com/100014222106738 то происходит редирект на профиль требуемого пользователя, в моём случае на https://www.facebook.com/sbuda.chapatso
Вопрос: как лучше и проще всего на PHP получить никнейм юзера sbuda.chapatso, если известен его ID 100014222106738

Answer (score 0):

при отправке запроса на страницу с айдишником  сервер дает ответ с заголовками, где указана страница перенаправления. Нужно прочесть все заголовки и выбрать оттуда `Location: https://www.facebook.com/sbuda.chapatso` .. дальше просто парсиш строку. Для получения данных ищи библиотеки для парсинга или CURL используй.. дело вкуса